# If condition is met, skip from 2nd iteration onwards

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#Can be more than two items also.
item_list = ["rpm", "exe"]

extraction_status = True
while extraction_status:
    file_status_flag = True
    
    file_status = some_other_function(arg1, arg2) # returns a nested dictionary of lists.
    
    for item in file_status['BU']: # file_status['BU'] = ["HR", "DEV" ,"Admin"]
        if item['extensions'] in item_list: #rpm or exe or zip
            if (file_status['status'] == "PUSHED")):
                print("file from {} reached target..".format(item))
                #do further action on that file
                continue # not working
            else:
                print("Status of {} is {}".format(item, file_status['status']))
    # To check if all the items in item_list has been pushed.               
    if (file_status_flag and (file_status['status'] == "PUSHED")):
        "All files reached target..make the script successful.."
        extraction_status = False
```

Let me explain, if HR is of status PUSHED, for the 1st time or iteration, do certain actions, from subsequent iteration onwards, skip if condition is met.

`continue` skips the current iteration, which I'm not looking for.

Is it possible ?

Example output

```
1st iteration:
file from BU reached target
file from DEV In Progress
file from Admin Not Prepared

2nd iteration: 
file from DEV In Progress
file from Admin In Progress
```

so on..

Comment: The 2nd iteration is the expected output you want to receive?

Comment: simply put, if the condition is met for the 1st time of the 1st iterable do certain actions and for further iterations even though the condition is met(for the 1st iterable), do nothing.
Hope I'm able to put that across

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add another flag to see if you already checked the condition? For example, we can add a flag called `already_checked`, set it to `True` on the first iteration and subsequently, if it's already `True` then skip doing further actions:

```py
item_list = ["rpm", "exe"]

extraction_status = True
while extraction_status:
    file_status_flag = True
    already_checked = False    # add this flag 
    
    file_status = some_other_function(arg1, arg2)
    
    for item in file_status['BU']: 
        if (item['extensions'] in item_list) and not already_checked:
            if (file_status['status'] == "PUSHED")):
                print("file from {} reached target..".format(item))
                #do further action on that file
                already_checked = True     # on the first successful iteration set the flag
            else:
                print("Status of {} is {}".format(item, file_status['status']))
    # To check if all the items in item_list has been pushed.               
    if (file_status_flag and (file_status['status'] == "PUSHED")):
        "All files reached target..make the script successful.."
        extraction_status = False
```

Comment: Yes, you're right but wanted to check if Python has any built in function to support this scenario, thanks.

Comment: @ChelMS, I don't think there's any specific built-in for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic I am aware to do that. But you can just use some extra variable:

```
#Can be more than two items also.
item_list = ["rpm", "exe"]

extraction_status = True
first_iteration = True

while extraction_status:
    file_status_flag = True
    
    file_status = some_other_function(arg1, arg2) # returns a nested dictionary of lists.
    # In case of next iterations we will skip first element. In case of bigger generators use itertools.islice 
    items = file_status['BU'][1:] if not_first_iteration else file_status['BU']
    for item in items: # file_status['BU'] = ["HR", "DEV" ,"Admin"]
        if item['extensions'] in item_list: #rpm or exe or zip
            if (file_status['status'] == "PUSHED")):
                print("file from {} reached target..".format(item))
                #do further action on that file
            else:
                print("Status of {} is {}".format(item, file_status['status']))
    # To check if all the items in item_list has been pushed.               
    if (file_status_flag and (file_status['status'] == "PUSHED")):
        "All files reached target..make the script successful.."
        extraction_status = False
    first_iteration = True
```

Comment: Cool, thats one nice  suggestion, thank you